# Change size of text box using attribute "contenteditable"

Tags: html, css

So I am trying to make a text editor with html, and I used a `<div>` element with `cotenteditable="true"` as an attribute. But I am struggling with using css to make the text box larger. As an example please refer to this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17WD1.png)

Anyways, any help would be appreciated, full source code below:

```html
<!-- This is the HTML -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Text Editor</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="editor.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="page.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat">
  </head>
  <body class="main">
    <h1>hello</h1>
    <p>hello</p>
    <div class="editor" contenteditable="true">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```css
//this is editor.css
.editor{
  background-color: #1d1f21;
  color: #c5c8c6;
  font-family: "Montserrat"
  font-weight: 100;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 200%;
  max-height: 200%;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

::selection{
  background: #373b41;
}
```

```css
//this is page.css
.main{
  background-color: #282a2e;
  color: #969896;
  font-family: "Raleway", "Montserrat";
  font-weight: 100;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a `min-height` to the text Field as below.

```
.editor{
  min-height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: You can set it as the answer on the left by clicking the correct sign